# Is there a way to add hair texture to 2d?

Tags: texturing, hair, 2d

Same as the title. I want to know a good way to get some hyper-realistic hair for 2d. Is this possible, or do I have to make a completely new 3d scene and add hair to that; if so, how?

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add reference  images that might help us understand what you are trying to do. ( to learn how to post images [read this link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491))

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can add a texture of hair exactly the same way you add any other textures for shaders for the rendering engine you use.

Will it look hyper-realistic or realistic or even good? Most likely no. Hair is visible outside the surface and because of that in most situations making hair in CG requires some sort of structure. There are many ways to create hair in Blender: hair particles could be used in multiple different ways or you could also use geometry with transparent textures, in some specific situations displacement or sculpting combined with texturing may work.